# ChartJS v2: Scale value at click coordinates (time scale)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a time-base line chart and I'm attempting to obtain the values for each scale at the click coordinates.

My onClick function specified in ChartJS options:

```
onClick: function(event, elementsAtEvent)
{
    console.log(event, elementsAtEvent, this);
    var valueX = null, valueY = null;
    for (var scaleName in this.scales) {
        var scale = this.scales[scaleName];
        console.log(scale.id, scale.isHorizontal());
        if (scale.isHorizontal()) {
            valueX = scale.getValueForPixel(event.offsetX);
        } else {
            valueY = scale.getValueForPixel(event.offsetY);
        }
    }
    console.log(event.offsetX, valueX, null, event.offsetY, valueY);
},
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AllenJB/dmebo9g5/1/

The code above appears to work well for the Y axis, but not the X (time scale) - it always returns the last value regardless of where in the chart you click.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code actually works fine. The only problem was that I was looking at the _i value of the moment object to check it's value (this is the value used as the initial input when creating the object, not necessarily the current value).

Changing the console.log line to the following yields the expected / correct result:

```
console.log(event.offsetX, valueX.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), null, event.offsetY, valueY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the nearest x axis value you could do it this way:

```
onClick: function (event) {

    const activeElements = this.getElementsAtXAxis(event);
    const xval = this.scales['x-axis-0']._timestamps.data[activeElements[0]._index];

    console.log(xval)

}
```